# Page goes almost completely white when I press alt or ctrl

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, jscalendar

I have my webpage. It looks great. But as soon as I press alt or ctrl, almost the whole webpage goes white. It only happens on one page of the site. Here are some screen shots.

**Before:**

[image: Before alt-key pressed]

**After:**

[image: After alt-key pressed]

**QUESTION:** Why is this happening?

I've looked all over my code trying to comment out things that may be causing it. The only things that are special about this page and the other pages I've been working on is that I use jsCalendar on this page, as well as svg images to make some water flow into little bubbles. I'm using the Foundation framework, and a lot of jQuery. There are no other special libraries I'm using. I can't share all the code because 1, it's a private company, and 2, it would involve sharing more than 1500 lines of code, and I'm sure none of you would want to look through that. And I can't make a more simple test case because I have no idea what part of the code is causing it. I'm looking for ideas as to why it's happening, and if you have specific pieces of code you would like to look at that might be causing it, I can post those. Thanks in advance!

**MORE INFO:** When I inspect the page in Chrome, the only element that seems to cover the entire page is `<div class="js-off-canvas-overlay is-overlay-fixed"></div>`, but when I delete it, nothing changes. There's still the big white thing.

Comment: **1-** Try to find what is that white element covering the rest... **2-** Look for keydown/keypress/keyup event handlers in your code. A nice freeware that I use for that kind of searches is [Agent Ransak](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. After looking at the code a bit further, I realized that the what-input library was putting some classes on the base `<html>` tag that was conflicting with one of my css selectors. I had some "key-something" classes that I was selecting using `[class*="key"]`, and then setting the width and height to `25px`. Thus, when I would hit a key on my keyboard, the `whatinput-types-keyboard` class was being added to the html tag, and thus, the width was being shrunk to `25px` too. So, it wasn't an element that was covering everything, it was the width of the whole `<html>` tag being shrunk by a bad selector. I changed the selector, and no longer have any more problems.